# Eclipse designation method- tips from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, shortcut

What does exactly mean these two signs ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

-The red one means: `private method`

-The yellow one means: `protected method`

Click [here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm) for more icon explanation.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can find much more info about icons here

http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm

Answer (score 1):

Those are visibility indicators. The red square means `private`, the yellow diamond `protected`, a green dot `public`, and a blue triangle no modifier i.e. package.

In this specific case you have to read the text to see where exactly the method is created.